# Cant do npm start on express generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, express, npm

I have npm 6.4.1 and node v10.15.3 on my windows so i tried installing Express Generator followed all the steps on the website and i am getting this when i try running npm start

```
> myapp@0.0.0 start C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\JS Basics\myapp
> node ./bin/www

Port 3000 requires elevated privileges
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-08T16_55_03_162Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your App name and port into Windows Firewall settings.

Comment: Thank u very much exactly what i needed it worked perfectly well https://www.veritas.com/content/support/en_US/article.100027250.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to run 3000 port on your system. 
Checkout the open ports on your system

`netstat -an | find /i`

See which are open and use those to run your app. I feel you wont be able have access and would need to run this command as administrator.

Comment: `> myapp@0.0.0 start C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\Documents\JS Basics\myapp
> node ./bin/www

Port 6767 requires elevated privileges
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ONLINEWIS-PROG-03\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-08T18_23_48_468Z-debug.log `

Answer (score -1):

The error says that running on that port requires "Elevated Privileges". Try running the command as Administrator if on Windows & with "sudo" if on linux.

Comment: samething i ran as admin on my windows still the same error

Comment: Send screenshot / Try a different port

Comment: i dont understand how?

Comment: Change your express server configuration to change the port to something other than 3000.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure you are not running it as administrator properly

Comment: I am actually running my command prompt as admin i did the installation on my ubuntu system and it working fine but i want to use it on my windows because its my home system